# Using Both Tagged And Untagged Data With XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I'm trying to parse some HTML using XPath in Java. Consider this HTML:

```
    <td class="postbody"> 
        <img src="...""><br />
<br />
<b>What is Blah?</b><br />
<br />
Blah blah blah
<br />
```

Note that "What Is Blah" is helpfully contained within a b tag and is therefore easily parseable. But "Blah blah blah" is out in the open, and so I can only pick it up by calling text() on its parent node.

Thing is, I need to go through this in sequence, putting the img down, then the bolded text, then the body text. It's important it ends up in order (it needn't be processed in order, if you can suggest a way that takes two passes).

So are there any suggestions for how, if I've got the above contained within a Java XPath node, I can go through it in turn and get what I need?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple, pure XPath solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an SAX based parser would be a better tool for this problem. It's event based so you can parse your XML document in order.

But it's an XML parser so you'll need to have a valid XML document. I never used [JTidy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/) but it's a java port of the HTML Tidy, so hopefully it can help you to transform your (invalid) HTML documents to a valid XML.

Comment: Ah! Already using JTidy. That's perfect. I'll try out some SAX parsing and report back. Any one you'd recommend?

Comment: SAX got the job done and was generally a lot cleaner than using XPath. Now I am a happy coding chimp once more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Use this XPath expression** evaluated with the parent of the provided XML fragment as the context node:

```
node()
```

This selects every node - child of the context node -- every element -child, every text-node-child, every comment-child and every PI (processing instruction) - child.

**In case you want to exclude comments and PIs, use**:

```
node()[not(self::comment() or self::processing-instruction)]
```

**In case that in addition to this you don't want to select the whitespace-only-text-nodes, use**:

```
node()
  [not(self::comment() or self::processing-instruction)]
    [not(self::text()[string-length() = 0])]
```

Comment: Thanks for this! There are some functions I didn't know existed in here. In the end I opted for SAX, but this'll come in handy in future!

Comment: @mtc06: Yes, XPath is quite powerful. I am glad you found my answer useful and you could confirm this by upvoting it. :)